# Crontab no toma hora correcta

Tags: date, centos, cron, crontab, proxmox

Tengo un inconveniente con una VM la cual tiene un crontab instalado.

El problema radica en que no ejecuta los Jobs en el tiempo definido.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al verificar el log del cron.. No muestra ningún error, sin embargo aparece una hora totalmente diferente en el log. Ejecuto el comando date y la fecha me la trae correctamente, ejecuto el comando timedatectl y este trae la hora correcta y la hora extraña que ejecuta el crontab.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He tratado de actualizar la hora extraña, con el comando hwclock --set. Sin embargo no he tenido éxito.

La VM es un Centos 7 y corre en un PROXMOX.

Saludos cordiales

Comment: Prueba reiniciando el sistema de log: `systemctl restart rsyslog`

Comment: Muchas gracias estimado, funciono perfectamente